# What does Codex take as tokens?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, language-model, tokenization

The typical default for neural networks in natural language processing has been to take words as tokens.

OpenAI Codex is based on GPT-3, but also deals with source code. For source code in general, there is no corresponding obvious choice of tokens, because each programming language has different rules for tokenizing. I don't get the impression Codex uses a separate tokenizer for each language.

What does it take as tokens?

Comment: Have you checked [the link on the website of OpenAI regarding their tokenizer](https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer)? It allows you to select their Codex model and paste in text to see how it gets tokenized. It seems to be using byte-pair encoding (BPE) to tokenize the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLP neural networks don't use word tokens any more. It's been a while since the norm is using subwords. Usual approaches to define the subword vocabulary are [byte-pair encoding (BPE)](https://aclanthology.org/P16-1162/), [word pieces](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter6/6?fw=pt) or [unigram tokenization](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/88831/14675).

[GPT-3 uses BPE tokenization](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14165). According to the OpenAI's tokenizer tool website:

> Codex models use a different set of encodings that handle whitespace more efficiently

From this, I understand that they use BPE but with a different vocabulary. This is supported by [this javascript tokenizer](https://github.com/botisan-ai/gpt3-tokenizer) that was created by extracting the BPE vocabulary from OpenAI's own online tokenizer tool.